# Do I need travel documents if my transit or stop in Dubai?

Tags: transit-visas, dubai

I have refugee travel documents from USA, I’m willing to travel to Iran but my transit is in Dubai and I have to wait in Dubai around 13 hours. Do I have to apply for any type of visa in order to stay in transit in Dubai?

Comment: What is your citizenship? Search engines such as Timatic and IATA typically require citizenship data and travel document type to be entered in order to get an answer.

Comment: Please note in addition to the above that refugees can transit Dubai, but cannot enter using refugee travel documents. You must stay airside.